# Java Makefile Error

Tags: java, makefile, package

I'm having this error when trying to compile my Java project with a Makefile I created.

Error:

**make:**  No rule to make target `src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output/*.class', needed by`classes'.  Stop.*

Makefile content:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
        src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/tokenizer/*.java \
        src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/core/*.java \
        src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output/*.java \
        src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/exceptions/*.java \
        src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/input/InputParser.java \
        src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/input/ReadInputString.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Can someone give me a hand with the Makefile please?

I'm using Eclipse btw.

Comment: the folder src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output has no java files, it seems?

Comment: Since you are using Eclipse, you should be able to **automatically** generate an Ant "build.xml".  Ant is vastly superior to Make for building Java code.

Comment: but I need to create a Makefile, build.xml is not an option..... @StephenC

Comment: all the files are the @uba.... thank you both!

Comment: Ummm ... that is not true.  If you can run Java on the build platform then you can also install and run Ant.  And you can always write your Makefile to run `ant` to build the Java code.

Comment: @StephenC In fairness, not all requirements are (a) technical or (b) reasonable.

Comment: @DaveNewton - But the flipside is that you (e.g. the OP) need to be prepared to "push back" on requirements that are not reasonable ... if there is a chance that it will work.  In this case, a technically unsound / unreasonable requirement is going to create a lot of unnecessary work and lead to a slow and/or fragile builds ... 'cos "someone" doesn't understand how bad an idea it is.

Comment: @DaveNewton - The worst thing that *we* can do is to fail to advise people like the OP of the consequences of their poor choices ... whether or not they were the people responsible for the choices.

Comment: @StephenC I'm pretty sure that's not the worst thing we can do. That aside, OP stated the reqs after you suggested Ant; the responsibility was fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either list all the source files individually or use the `wildcard` directive in Makefile to automatically match the files instead.

Also from your comments it looks like the package names for the java files are `edu.osu.lispinterpreter.*`.

So I would suggest to move the `Makefile` to the `src` directory and make these changes in the Makefile.

```
CLASSES := $(wildcard edu/osu/lispinterpreter/tokenizer/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard edu/osu/lispinterpreter/core/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard edu/osu/lispinterpreter/exceptions/*.java)
CLASSES += edu/osu/lispinterpreter/input/InputParser.java
CLASSES += edu/osu/lispinterpreter/input/ReadInputString.java
```

The java compiler should be able to pick up definitions of classes from other packages as long as the package name corresponds to the directory structure without writing any explicit dependencies in the `Makefile`.

Comment: I tried that, but now it throws this error: src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/tokenizer/Tokenizer.java:4: package edu.osu.lispinterpreter.exceptions does not exist

Comment: should I put them in a specific order?

Comment: You should define dependencies in your Makefile, that is what a `Makefile` is for. :)

Comment: great! in which section of the file should I put that?

Comment: You can define it after this line: `classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)`. Since that by itself is another dependency rule, make sure to add a new line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25867/discussion-between-tuxdude-and-cacho)

Comment: Thats the exact answer! The problem was that the Makefile should be located inside the "src" folder..... The wildcard saved me also! Thanks @Tuxdude! Amazing help! :O)

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Pitfall.html#Wildcard-Pitfall

> When a wildcard matches no files, it is left as it is

It seems src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output is empty, so src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output/*.java does not match any file and is left as it is, which is not what is intended. Using the [wildcard function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function), this can be avoided.

The solution would be to replace

```
src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output/*.java
```

by

```
$(wildcard src/edu/osu/lispinterpreter/output/*.java)
```

and so on for all the other lines, I think

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that your use of `*` in the `CLASSES` variable.  The way you have written that variable, it is being populated with a list of "file names" that have `*` characters in them ... which will propagate through the rest of the processing.

You either need to list the classes individually, or do something to tell Make to "glob" the list.  If you are using GNU Make then the wildcard function should do the trick.

But note that won't work on other versions of Make, so you've got a Makefile portability problem.  (Which brings me back to my comment that Ant is better.)

---

And once you've gotten past that, you have the problem that if you are compile Java classes one at a time:

- your build will be really slow ... 'cos each `javac` command incurs a JVM startup (assuming you are using the Hotspot or OpenJDK tool chains),
- you have to build the classes in the right order ... according to the dependencies inherent in the source code,
- you have to add those dependencies to the Makefile (!!!), and
- if you have dependency cycles, you've got problems!

With enough patience, you could build a Makefile that coped with this, but it is really tricky, and the resulting Makefile will be fragile.  Realistic alternatives are:

- just build all of the */*.java files in one `javac` command, irrespective of dependencies,
- add a "make depend" rule that uses something to analyse the source code or bytecode files and *generate* the dependencies in the Makefile.

Or just use Ant.

References:

- [Why is no one using make for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209827/why-is-no-one-using-make-for-java)
- A Java / Make dependency generator - http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cxh/java/javadepend/
- Another Makefile generator for Java - http://www.tildeslash.com/mmake/mmake.html