# Compile a non-C/C++ project crossplatform from CLI

Tags: compilation, makefile, cross-platform, project

Say we have a project in a non-C/C++ language, consisting of a bunch of source files. How can we use `make` or a similar tool to compile this bunch from commandline? It should just compile every source file in the project directory and create an executable from this. Doesn't sound too difficult, but I can't seem to find a simple answer on this.

Comment: What have you tried? It is a simple 3-liner, after all, and we will understand your problem better if you show your specific code and tell exactly what's wrong with its output.

Comment: I'm currently coding C#, and googled on 'makefile template C#' and stuff, but didn't find anything. What is that 3-liner you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be more specific about the language and the platforms you need to compile on?

The compilation process is different for different languages/platforms. For instance, you might not want to use `make` to compile something written in Java:
[Why is no one using make for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209827/why-is-no-one-using-make-for-java)
(at least, not the same way as for C++)

Comment: That explains a bit. Useful article! So in fact a build program is essentially language specific. This would mean that I should read up on writing project files for C#.

Answer (score 1):

`make`s pattern rules are fairly powerful. Suppose you want to build the programs `a`, `b` and `c` from the C# source files `a.cs`, `b.cs` and `c.cs`, the Makefile looks like:

```
all : a.exe b.exe c.exe

%.exe : %.cs
     csc.exe /out:$@ $^
```

The first rule in the file tells `make` what to do. It is named `all` by convention. The second rule is a template that defines how file names ending on `.exe` can be made with the same name ending on `.cs` by invoking the compiler as given on the next line. Remember to place a tab in front of the last line.

`$^` and `$@` are automatic variables, meaning "target name" and "all prerequisites", respectively.