Make command does not work - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when re-making GnuCash documentation
I am trying to re-make the GnuCash documentation (processed via DocBook) on my machine and tried to tweak a few settings.
Based on https://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/html/labels.html,  I inserted the settings
<xsl:param name="section.autolabel" select="1"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="section.autolabel.max.depth">8</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="section.label.includes.component.label" select="1"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="paper.type">A4</xsl:param>

in general-customization.xsl.
Then I followed theInitialization setup pretty much to the letter. For the sake of completeness and as far as I looked around on the official pages, the requirements for software packages seems to be on their github page for the official documentation.
However, the make command does not work. The following happens:
$ pwd
/[...]/Finanzen/GnuCash/gnucash-docs/build
$ make de-guide-pdf

[  0%] Generating ../../share/doc/de/gnucash-guide.pdf
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:27 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
WARNUNG: Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:27 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
WARNUNG: Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:27 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
WARNUNG: Hyphenation pattern not found. URI: de.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:27 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #1.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:27 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #2.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:27 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #3.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:27 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #4.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:28 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #5.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:28 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #6.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:28 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #7.
Dez. 05, 2024 1:57:28 PM org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent processEvent
INFORMATION: Rendered page #8.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.fop.svg.SimpleSVGUserAgent.setSourceResolution(float)'
    at org.apache.fop.svg.SimpleSVGUserAgent.<init>(SimpleSVGUserAgent.java:55)
    at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader$1.<init>(PreloaderSVG.java:166)
    at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.createImageInfo(PreloaderSVG.java:166)
    at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.getImage(PreloaderSVG.java:131)
    at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.access$200(PreloaderSVG.java:108)
    at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG.preloadImage(PreloaderSVG.java:76)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.preloadImage(ImageManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.cache.ImageCache.needImageInfo(ImageCache.java:127)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.getImageInfo(ImageManager.java:123)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.flow.ExternalGraphic.bind(ExternalGraphic.java:81)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FObj.processNode(FObj.java:131)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:321)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$2.run(FOTreeBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$2.run(FOTreeBuilder.java:182)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:181)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.closeStartTag(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:206)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToSAXHandler.flushPending(ToSAXHandler.java:250)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.endElement(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:245)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:619)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:184)
    [...]

Do I need to install some SVG-packages for FOP or... batik software for Java? I must say, I am way out of my depth here.
Some more basic info:
$ uname -r
6.12.1-arch1-1
$ pacman -Q fop
fop 2.10-1
$ pacman -Q libxslt
libxslt 1.1.42-1
$ pacman -Q java-batik 
java-batik 1.17-1
$ pacman -Q java-xmlgraphics-commons 
java-xmlgraphics-commons 2.9-1


I'm impressed that there are still people using Make out there. For reference there are 14 years old discussion of nobody using it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209827/why-is-no-one-using-make-for-java

ITYM "using Make for java builds out there".

Oh, alright. Awesome. Cool.
Help :(

This is an utterly bizarre error. A class file has been compiled against a certain library (think 'h files' if you're more familiar with C) where at runtime the availability of methods is different than it was at compile time. Except the one it has a version conflict with is.. itself. Which is not possible. Apache Batik is an SVG renderer written in java.

@rzwitserloot Thank you for your comment. If you happen to have an idea or guess what I could try to make it work, I'd definitely appreciate any sort of info. :)

@henry If I were in your shoes here I'd first try to replace the batik binary that's being used with the newest one you can find online. Because whatever this one appears to be downloading, it's broken. Then, it most likely still works fine on its own but fails in this build, then I'd toy around with the classpath where-ever make is invoking java to run this stuff, and look if 2 different versions of the same library are both on it, and remove the older one.
